# Is there a way to read NFT metadata in the anchor program(rust)?

Tags: rust, solana

I tried using mint account info (which obviously wouldn't work) and I also tried to deserialise the `mint.to_account_info().data` into the metadata struct from the `mpl_token_metadata::state::Metadata`. This gave errors.

I need the `sellerFeeBasisPoints` and the creators info from the NFT Metadata.

Also, is there a way to update the `primarySaleHappened` parameter? (I am writing a custom auction contract for an NFT Marketplace).

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please show us some code and which errors you got.

Comment: I lost my code, but I was using the wrong approach for the same. I was doing something like:


`let mint_account = ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info();


let mint_metadata = &mint_account.data;


msg!("mint account {:?}", mint_account);

msg!("mint metadata {:?}", mint_metadata);`

Comment: Please create two questions since your questions target in two different areas.

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize the `Metadata`-struct by using the `mpl_token_metadata`-crate provided by Metaplex:

```
use mpl_token_metadata::state::Metadata;
let metadata: Metadata = Metadata::from_account_info(metadata_account_info)?;
```

For your second question, please open a new question.

Comment: how to access the data now like this Metadata->name ?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question if you are planning to update the `primarySaleHappened`  from the program then you can do a CPI (Cross Program Invocation) to the Token metadata program to this function `update_primary_sale_happened_via_token`. Similarly, you can find `createUpdatePrimarySaleHappenedViaTokenInstruction` in the `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` npm package to do it in the js/ts side.